Jquery - search by element node and remove the node from parent
I am trying to search by elementNode. I don't have class or id.
var searchNode = `<div>
                  <header></header>
            </div>`;

var parentNode = `<div class="parent">
                     ..........
                     <div>
                       <header></header>
                     </div>
                 </div>`;

I am trying like
$(parentNode).remove($(searchNode))

which is not working.
Can someone help me how to remove the searchNode from parentNode.

try $(".parent header").remove();
you can refer : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-remove-method/

those nodes are actually two separate nodes.. you cannot find the substree like that in the parent node. So before doing any attempt I first need to ask: are you expecting to create a dom structure from parentNode string and then removing from it the subtree matching the html contained in the searchNode string?

I am able to figure out somehow. I looped through the parent node till I find the exact header node
if(($(node)[0].isEqualNode($(headingNode)[0])) {
do whatever operation
}

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
